# How to overide static variables?

Tags: php, static

I have a class App with static and non static variables.

```
class App{
    protected static $appName = 'dummy';
    protected $appIcon = 'icon';

    public static function getAppName() {
        return self::$appName;
    }
}
```

Then I extend this class like this

```
class Notepad extends App{
    private static $appName = 'notepad';
    private $appIcon = 'notepad_icon';
}
```

I want to get appName without creating an instance of Notepad. I tried Notepad::getAppName() but this returns always dummy.

Any ideas or suggestions???

Thanks in advance!

J!

**After Sergey's post:**

I was wandering which is the most OOP way to do something like this, and the most efficient (speed/memory)?

```
a. declaring variables as puplic

b. creating an instance of an object just to get a few variables

c. rewrite the static function to all the children classes as Sergey suggested
```

Comment: a. declaring variables as puplic - is most efficient, use statis variable if you want to change it, if you not, use const for your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have a new keyword "static" in php > 5.3.

I changed your example:

```
class App{
    protected static $appName = 'dummy';
    protected $appIcon = 'icon';

    public static function getAppName() {
        return static::$appName;
    }
}

class Notepad extends App{
    protected static $appName = 'notepad';
    protected $appIcon = 'notepad_icon';
}
```

This way Notepad::getAppName() will return 'notepad';
More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a better solution

```
class App{
    protected static $appName = 'dummy';
    protected $appIcon = 'icon';

    public static function getAppName() {
        $c = get_called_class();
        return $c::$appName;
    }
}
```

Now it works the way it should!!!

Answer (score 0):

function getAppName() call for App class, and self::$appName point to App::$appName
if you want overrided value you have to write like :

```
class Notepad extends App{
    protected static $appName = 'notepad';
    protected $appIcon = 'notepad_icon';
    public static function getAppName() {
        return self::$appName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. There is no way without re declaring getAppName() ?